# Python printing binary value and its decimal form

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, decimal, bit

Python 2.6/2.7

I have the following program.

```
print 0b10

def p_m(x):
    print x

p_m(bin(2))
```

**Output:**

```
2
0b10
```

What I wanted to print in p_m() is 2 (the decimal value) of "0b10" which is what I'm passing to p_m() as first argument and getting this value "0b10" in variable x and just printing that x.

Why `print x` inside the function is NOT working like the first line in the program?

What should I do in p_m()'s print statement to print the value of "*0b10*" as **2**.

Comment: `0b10` is an `int`. `bin(2)` is `'0b10'` which is a string. You'd have to `print int('0b10', 2)` to get it to print 2

Comment: @M.Klugerford Thanks. Didn't check if int() can pass base values as 2. Thanks. If you can answer, I'll mark it. BTW, giving print int(x,10) didn't work, I guess because 0b10 is not a valid value for base 10(decimals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0b10` is an int. `bin(2)` is '0b10' which is a string. You'd have to print `int('0b10', 2)` to get it to print 2

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string `0b10` back to int using [2 base parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
def p_m(x):
    print int(x, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`print 0b10` gives 2.

This is because all the numbers are stored in python as binary.

`bin(2)` is a string. So it gives you the binary value.

You can use `print int('0b10', 2)`. Here 2 means the base and '0b10' is the binary you want to convert. `0b` part of `0b10` is not mandatory since `int()` already knows it converts it to base 2. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) says,

> The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2-36. Base-2, -8,
>   and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O/0, or
>   0x/0X, as with integer literals in code.

Comment: Is there no difference between these 2 lines. 1: print int("0b100",2) and 
2: print int("100",2). They both print decimal number 4. Int() first param is a string and 2nd is a base (2) so in this case, it thinks string values: 0b100 and 100 are both same, but it's confusing when we thing it as strings.